# How to queue jobs by curl_multi_init or multi-threading in PHP?

Tags: php, multithreading, curl, php-curl

I try to use `curl_multi_init` for a large list of URLs. Since `curl_multi_init` sends `n` requests simultaneously, I came out with the following solution to send the requests in batches (as I cannot send all requests, 10000+ at the same time).

```
foreach($urls as $i=>$url{
    $ar[$i]=$url;

    if($j%10==0){

        foreach($ar as $i=>$n){
            ${$ch.$i} = curl_init();
            curl_setopt(${$ch.$i}, CURLOPT_URL,$n);
        }

        $mh = curl_multi_init();
        foreach($ar as $i=>$n){
            curl_multi_add_handle($mh,${$ch.$i} );
        }

        do {
            $status = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
            if ($active) {curl_multi_select($mh);}
        } while ($active && $status == CURLM_OK);


        foreach($ar as $i=>$n){
            $results[$i]=curl_multi_getcontent(${$ch.$i} );
            curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, ${$ch.$i} );
        }

        $ar=array();
    }
$j++;
}
```

The problem is that there is no queuing mechanism here. This means when 9 jobs are completed, it waits for the 10th job to be finished before starting the next batch (10 requests).

I look for a queuing mechanism to always send 10 requests. When a job is a finish, start the next one in the queue.

Since I am not sure if `curl_multi_init` is capable of doing it, I welcome any multithreading solution. The only requirement is that the whole process should be conducted in one single script.